# Connection reset while reading file from GCS bucket

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm experiencing weird issue while reading text file (CSV) stored in GCS bucket. It is being uploaded correctly but during processing it I'm getting two types of errors:

`read: connection reset by peer`

or

`ERR: unexpected EOF`

Sometimes occurs one of them, sometimes another (the file processing is being stopped) but sometimes it works without problem (the file processing ends successfully).

I have GKE cluster version 1.22.15-gke.2500, I'm authenticating by service account HMAC and the SA has Storage Admin role assigned. I'm also using minio-go/v7.0.46 client to connect from pod to GCS bucket.

I've investigated logs but haven't found any clues what could be the reason. I suspect GCS or GKE or MinIO bug but maybe someone had similar problem.

Does anyone has idea what could be the reason of the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

‘connection reset by peer’ means a connection issue. Looks like GCS is closing the connection prematurely or an intermediate proxy in the company is closing the connection prematurely. This doesn't look like a minio-go issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you going through a GCP load balancer?  If you are, it must be the "classic" one, not the other one. I don't remember all the specifics when we ran into this, but it had nothing to do with our Python code.